# update function from my profile controller doent change data ffrom DB

Tags: php, laravel, put

after i submit my edited form nothing changes in the database i want to explain more but its hard for me  with english i hope you understand.
well i want to make a view for profile updating :

here is my my view :

```
<div class="row contact_form_row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="contact_form_container">
                        <form method="PUT" action="{{ route('profile.update',auth()->id()) }}" class="contact_form text-center" id="contact_form">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                            <div class="row">
                            @foreach ($infos as $infos)

                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <label>  Nom : </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="name" value="{{$infos->name}}" required="required">

                                    </div>
                                    <label> E-mail : </label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                                        <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="email" value="{{$infos->email}}" required="required">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <label> Numero de telephone : </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="tele_user" value="{{$infos->tele_user}}" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <label> Adresse personnalisée : </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="adresse" value="{{$infos->adresse}}" required="required">
                                    </div>


                                </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <label> Presentation : </label>

                                        <textarea class="contact_textarea contact_input" name="presentation" placeholder="presentation"  required="required">{{$infos->presentation}}</textarea>

                                    </div>
                            @endforeach 

                                    <button class="contact_button right" type="submit">Valider!</button>

                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and here is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\User;
use App\users;
use App\http_request; 


class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $infos = DB::table('users')
            ->where('users.id',auth()->user()->id)
            ->join('ville','ville.ID_Ville','=','users.ID_Ville')
            ->join('region','region.ID_REGION','=','ville.ID_REGION')

            ->get();
        return view('profile')->with('infos',$infos);
    }
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //$user = users::find($id);
        $user = DB::table('users')
            ->select('users.*')
            ->where('user.id', $id);

        $user->nom =$request->input('nom');
        $user->email =$request->input('email');
        $user->tele_user =$request->input('tele_user');
        $user->adresse =$request->input('adresse');
        $user->presentation =$request->input('presentation');
        $user->save();


        $infos = DB::table('users')
            ->where('users.id',auth()->user()->id)
            ->join('ville','ville.ID_Ville','=','users.ID_Ville')
            ->join('region','region.ID_REGION','=','ville.ID_REGION')

            ->get();

        return view('/profile')->with('infos',$infos);
    }
```

}

after i submit i get a white page instead of the the view /profile with and url :

```
http://localhost/testprojet/public/profile/1?_token=R4cTYZuLPX9shqkg0i2JKoCwx7g23PbRc5Vhke5A&_method=PUT&name=Othmaneee&email=othmane.messaoud%40gmail.com&tele_user=642213124&adresse=Maroc%2C+Rabat+Al+Irfan+ENSIAS&presentation=je+m%27appelle+othmane+
```

it means that the information passed but nothing changes in the database
any help please

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a 
    }
At the end of your file to close the class

```
 PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in your code on line 49
```

Comment: if you maen } at the end of the controller, i just add it here but it exist already on my original code and its not the probleme